# Second Controller can't find .html

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

First controller works correctly,

```
@Controller
@ComponentScan
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class MainController {
 @RequestMapping("/profile")
    private String g(){
        return "Profile.html";
    }
}
```

Second:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/gallery")
public class GContoller {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/month")
    String ffff() {
        return "monthGallery.html";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/test")
    @ResponseBody
    String test() {
        return "Test";
    }
}
```

Page `localhost:8080/gallery/test` opens and display "test", but `localhost:8080/gallery/month` opens with 404 error. Obviosly, that 2nd controller can't find file monthGallery.html. All htmls are in /webapp.

Project structure

`/java
     /com.example.xxx
/webapp`

Comment: Try adding below annotations to Gcontroller.java class:@ComponentScan
@EnableAutoConfiguration

Comment: It's not helping. I tried

Comment: Pls share exception trace

Comment: @DarkKnight There isn't exception. Only 404 in browser. If annotate 2nd controller by @EnableWebMvc exception:  `Could not resolve view with name 'monthGallery' in servlet with name 'dispatcherServlet'`

Comment: @Leonid Are you using thymeleaf to render the views? Do you have a html called monthGallery.html? Anyway, return just "monthGallery" without ..html

Comment: @cralfaro I don't use thymeleaf, I tried this variants too

Comment: @LeonidLunin I just tried yours examples and work for me, could you send also your Application class?

Comment: Is this a springboot app? As far as I remember, spring boot apps htmls are supposed to be at /resources/templates/*.html. Also you don't return the full name, so instead of "monthGallery.html" it would be "monthGallery". I have created a sample springboot app and it in fact works like I said.

Comment: @dambros I use the same html in 1st controller by "monthGallery.html"

Comment: @LeonidLunin i am confuse now, is a Spring-Boot app? or just spring mvc?

Comment: @cralfaro spring-boot

Comment: Then @dambros is right, you have to create all yours templates under "resources/templates" and in your Controllers just make reference to them by name, not .html suffix needed. Try that and will work

Comment: @cralfaro http://puu.sh/nYk7i/de502057ee.png
see this structure. It isn't working. Without annotations the same

Comment: @LeonidLunin I would start from scratch from a clean project, no webapps folder, rights annotations, just keep on eye to this example, and tell us if you can make it work  https://spring.io/guides/gs/serving-web-content/

Comment: Remove `@ComponentScan` and `@EnableConfiguration` from the controller. Refer to [this](https://spring.io/guides/gs/serving-web-content/) for further instructions please.

Comment: @dambros The same, I wrote it.

Comment: @LeonidLunin put your code somewhere we can see it in its enterity because I am pretty sure there are some things misplaced. I just yesterday followed the given tutorial and it should work.

Comment: @dambros I made pure project in Spring Boot Initlizer and nothing working. First controller correctly works with /resources/static/ and 2nt isn't working. I don't know where mistake can be.

Comment: @LeonidLunin can you put your project on github so I can see what is going on? I have a spring boot sample code here with a couple of different controllers and html and they work as specified on the arcticle.